# Google chrome autofill is not working on all machines

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, autocomplete

I developed a pages and I put autocomplete attributes in every text input according to google https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill?hl=en , but the problem is very strange. The problem is taht it is working on my machine properly and after deploying on my test environment it working there as well but only on my machine, when I am testing it on other team members machine it is not working there.

Th form that I made is exactly same as this form https://greenido.github.io/Product-Site-101/form-cc-example.html.

If you test it in you chrome browser it'll work for you, I also have added personal information into chrome by going through advanced setting and filling autofill profile there.

As you can test my plunker example to test and see problem. https://embed.plnkr.co/SKkAJ2lHQHElNbyvGrmp/

I have searched a lot for solution but nothing was related to this, like people are talking about autocomplete off, go to google chrome setting and setting profile and etc.

Comment: not working means, what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `<form>` and put data-input attribute it'll work.

```
<form>
<input type="text" required ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Name" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="250" data-input="name" autocomplete="name" /> <input type="email" required ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Email" name="Email" id="Email" maxlength="100" data-input="email" autocomplete="email" /> <input type="text" required ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Mobile" name="Mobile" id="Mobile" maxlength="30" data-input="tel" autocomplete="tel" />
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Telephone" name="Telephone" id="Telephone" maxlength="30" data-input="tel" autocomplete="tel" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `input` tag the `name` attribute start with uppercase latter
try to change it lowercase latter and it should work

your code:

```
Name: <input type="text" required="" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Name" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="250" autocomplete="name"> <br> <br>
Email: <input type="email" required="" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Email" name="Email" id="Email" maxlength="100" autocomplete="email"> <br> <br>
Mobile: <input type="text" required="" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Mobile" name="Mobile" id="Mobile" maxlength="30" autocomplete="tel"> <br> <br>
Phone: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Telephone" name="Telephone" id="Telephone" maxlength="30" autocomplete="tel"> <br> <br>
```

fix code

```
Name: <input type="text" required="" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Name" name="name" id="Name" maxlength="250" autocomplete="name"> <br> <br>
Email: <input type="email" required="" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Email" name="email" id="Email" maxlength="100" autocomplete="email"> <br> <br>
Mobile: <input type="text" required="" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Mobile" name="mobile" id="Mobile" maxlength="30" autocomplete="tel"> <br> <br>
Phone: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.Model.Contact.Telephone" name="telephone" id="Telephone" maxlength="30" autocomplete="tel"> <br> <br>
```

Comment: Hi Zamboney, thanks your answer, it doesn't matter the name should start with uppercase becuase functionality is alreay working with this uppercase. The problem is something else that me and you haven't yet catch. I have tested your answer on other machines but is not working as well.

Comment: you can see in the link you add that the name of the attribute is in lowercase

Comment: HI Zamboney, I found the solution for this problem, chrome autofill needed the <form> element around it with attribute autocomplete='on' then it works fine on all test machines.